# Do constant static fields cause memory leak in an web application?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I know that static field can cause a memory leak, because they will not be GCed.

But when there is an web application which is deployed in a container (such as Tomcat), each application has its own ClassLoader, and it can be undeployed.

My question is, do garbage collector claims objects referenced by static members of the classes which are going to be unloaded?

The simplest case is a singleton (implemented by an static variable referencing self), will it be GCed if the application is undeployed?

Comment: To my knowledge, static fields *are* GCed, if the class is GCed.

Comment: Ok, but will a class be GCed if it is referenced by an static field? For example in singletons....

Comment: If the class is referenced by it's own static field then that would not prevent collection.  And keep in mind that a singleton can't be referenced without naming the class.  Naming the class (outside of a character string) is a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might answer your question:

> When an app is stopped, Tomcat (even before 6.0.24) nullifies the
>   value of all static class variables of classes loaded by the
>   WebAppClassLoader. In some cases, it may fix a classloader leak (for
>   example because of a custom ThreadLocal class, see above), but even if
>   we still have a leak, it may decrease the amount of memory lost

You can read more [here](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection#staticClassVariables)

Cheers !!

Comment: What about `static final` fields? I believe it's about non-final static fields,  isn't it?

Comment: The example in provided link is a `final static` byte array, how could it clean up that?